# How do a make an object inside a class more accesible than the class I used to create that object?

Tags: c#

```
class A {
    class B {
    }
    public B BObject = new B();
}
```

I want to use the object **BObject** when I create an **instance of A** but I don't want to be able to access the **class B**. I searched a lot and I've tried a lot things but I didn't find anything. I would like to know if there's a way to do this.

```
A AOBject = new A();
a.BObject; //I want this
a.B; //But not this
```

Comment: That's not possible, the compiler (e.g. in a consuming app) could not work with `BObject` without knowing the type. You may consider using a base class or interface instead and hide the specific implementation.

Comment: How should anyone using `BObject` know what he/she can do with that object, if he/she´s not able to access that particular type? Why exactly do you want that? What do you want to **achieve** here?

Comment: How do you want to use that? Post the full expression you're having troubles with.

Comment: "I don't want to be able to access the class B." this is a very confusing statement. "a.B; //But not this" this is even more confusing. `a` is the variable name of an instance of the type `A` and `B` is a **Type**! the last statement is not even compileable. What do you actually mean

Comment: @HimBromBeere the real code I'm using it's to create a class Menu, and the fields are objects (for example the Title, Options, each one withe properties like color, content and so on). So I'm just interested in use the object as a field, being able to access the class which I used to create them would not make sense. (I hope this explanation is better).

Answer (score 1):

If someone must use your type he must know it.

But you could use an interface for that class to hide everything not related:

```
interface IBModel
{
    // define properties or methods that should be visible
}

class A
{
    class B: IBModel
    {
    }
    public IBModel BObject = new B();
}
```

Instead of let `B` implement it you could also create a new class that is just a mapper for the original `B`-type. On that way it's not even possible to get `B` via casting.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but with a little modification.

In your example, the caller of `a.BObject;` get a `A.B`, then the caller need to know `A.B` to know what to deal with.

But you can mask the class `A.B` with a interface. You can create a public interface `IB` will represent the contract of B

```cs
class A {
    public interface IB {}
    private class B : IB {}

    public IB BObject = new B();
}
```

In this case :

```cs
A AOBject = new A();
a.BObject; // OK, because A.IB is public
a.B; // KO, because A.B is private
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) for more information concerning interface.